# When a new consumer comes online, can it read the last x messages?

Tags: rabbitmq

I'm confused how rabbitmq works when a new consumer comes online.

I understand when there are currently x number of consumers connected, and then a producer sends a message the consumers will receive these messages.

But say consumerX was down, and now comes online or it is a brand new consumer.  Is it possible for it to replay messages in the past 24 hours?

Answer (score 0):

This is a normal behavior for RabbitMQ.

Please read:
https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-python.html

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible for it to replay messages in the past 24 hours?

It depends on how you set things up.

If you have queues that don't auto-delete, they'll just keep collecting messages and waiting around for a consumer to connect.

I've had instances w/ thousands of messages stuck in a queue because my consumer was crashing. As soon as I fixed my code, the messages started consuming again.

But, if you're letting your queues get deleted when your consumers die, then you're in a bit of trouble.

There is a plugin to read the last ## of messages from an exchange, but it doesn't work in a time-based manner... just the last ## of messages: https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-recent-history-exchange